# Excel VBA extrapolate values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that has data stored in it the following way (weekly data example)

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|          |   WK1    |   WK2    |   WK3    |   WK4    |   WK5    |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| DT Begin | 29.12.14 | 05.01.15 | 12.01.15 | 19.01.15 | 26.01.15 |
| DT End   | 04.01.15 | 11.01.15 | 18.01.15 | 25.01.15 | 01.02.15 |
| XData    | 50       | 10       | 10       | 10       | 50       |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

My problem ist to aggregate the XData on a monthly basis. For that I want to break the data down for days and then calculate the average.

**Edit:** I changed the table as it was not clear what I meant. This averages to ((50*4)+(10*21)+(5*50))/31 = 22.90

```
+------------+-------+
|    Date    | Value |
+------------+-------+
| 01.01.2015 | 50    |
| 02.01.2015 | 50    |
| 03.01.2015 | 50    |
| 04.01.2015 | 50    |
| 05.01.2015 | 10    |
| 06.01.2015 | 10    |
| 07.01.2015 | 10    |
| 08.01.2015 | 10    |
| 09.01.2015 | 10    |
| 10.01.2015 | 10    |
| 11.01.2015 | 10    |
| 12.01.2015 | 10    |
| 13.01.2015 | 10    |
| 14.01.2015 | 10    |
| 15.01.2015 | 10    |
| 16.01.2015 | 10    |
| 17.01.2015 | 10    |
| 18.01.2015 | 10    |
| 19.01.2015 | 10    |
| 20.01.2015 | 10    |
| 21.01.2015 | 10    |
| 22.01.2015 | 10    |
| 23.01.2015 | 10    |
| 24.01.2015 | 10    |
| 25.01.2015 | 10    |
| 26.01.2015 | 50    |
| 27.01.2015 | 50    |
| 28.01.2015 | 50    |
| 29.01.2015 | 50    |
| 30.01.2015 | 50    |
| 31.01.2015 | 50    |
+------------+-------+
| Average    | 22.90 |
+------------+-------+
```

After having done this calculation I want to summarize the data as follows for the entire year:

```
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+
|       |  Jan  |  Feb  | Mar  | ...  |
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+
| XData | 22.90 | 22.00 | 23.1 | ...  |
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+
```

Being a newbie in Excel VBA, I have extreme trouble doing this.

I know how to get to the value of a cell (Range.Value) but not how to find data in a particular week (as WK1 is there for 2014 as well) Range.Find with a date other than the one in the cell itself does not seem to work.

Whar I am asking for is a way to approach this problem. My particular difficulties are to:

1. Find the data in the worksheet
2. split the week values into day values (see table above)
3. Copy the data or hold it in some sort of data structure
4. calculate the average (this should be ease then)
5. fill in the data on a monthly basis

As you can see, I have trouble even getting started - any hints would be greatly appreciated. Maybe I'm thinking of this entirely too complicated? Thank you!

Comment: I am almost 100% certain you can do this with formulas only. However, how do you calc your average? `22.90` does not make sense to me as shown in your example.

Comment: Very strange question

1. About find: you know week has 7 day, one week is one cells. If year begin from Monday number of cell is number of day in a year divide on 7. If year not begin from Monday then search number a day of first Sunday then decrease your day by  this number then divide by 7

2 What data split into day values?

Comment: 2 What data split into day values?

3. Range(......).Copy

4. How you calculate your average? Show your formula

5. .Cells(1, 1).VALUE=0 input 0 in A1

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I tried to improve my question by showing exactly what I mean with splitting the values into day values and then creating the average. In my mind, the week values provided are valid for each day of the week. To match them to the month I need to create a table like the one I edited above. Is there a better way? I'll try to do it with formulas and without VBA, but since I have to do it for multiple sheets in a workbook, I was thinking of VBA - only that way I was able to always find the correct row.

Comment: @Ivan.s Maybe my edited table makes it more clear.

Comment: why your read a date from table in cells DT begin, DT end (if you have full tale over year)?  To make your task you need only one variable -- year!!!

use this function in vba 
Weekday(date) -day of the week;
Day(date) - representing the day of the month;
Month(date) - representing the month of the year;
Year(date) - representing the year;
To determine leap year use function 
`Function YearIsLeap(mYear)
    YearIsLeap = IsDate("2/29/" & CStr(mYear))
End Function`